# Проблема с Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position); в Unity 2D

Tags: c#, unity3d

я создаю платформер на Unity. У меня есть враг, в нем есть такая строка `float distToplaeyr = Vector2.Distance(transform.position, player.position);`, проблема в том что, когда я стою в притык рядом с врагом distToplaeyr  = 10,45.В интернете про это я ничего не нашел, поэтому просто вычел 10. Потом появилась другая проблема - если я начинаю залазить на возвышенность distToplaeyr  уменьшается(Пример: я стаю на земле distToplaeyr = 4, я поднимаюсь вверх distToplaeyr = 1.What?)
Как мне это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

можно попробовать вычислить дистанцию "вручную".

```
    X1 = transform.position.X;
    X2 = player.position.X;
    Y1 = transform.position.Y;
    Y2 = player.position.Y;
    distToplaeyr = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(X1-X2, 2) +  Math.Pow(Y1-Y2, 2))
```